# Request to provide query to delete duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Case-1**

**If all the records are in Exception status for that particular Ref_No**

Delete all the records except first record

**Case-2**

**If some records are in Exception status and one in Matched status for that particular Ref_No**

Delete all the records who's status are in Exception

Below query is working fine for Case-2 but not working for Case-1. Request someone to help with the query.

```
with cte
       as (
       select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Ref_No order by Id) RN ,* from 
      Table1
       )
                     
 Delete from cte where Final_status <> 'MATCHED'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Dale K for making question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "exception" and "matched" are the only options for final status, then you can `ORDER BY Final_Status DESC` in your row_number.  And then add a WHERE condition to never delete RN=1

```
with cte
       as (
       select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Ref_No order by Final_Status DESC, Id) RN ,* from 
      Table1
       )
                     
Delete from cte 
where Final_status <> 'MATCHED'
AND RN>1
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets around the need to assume there are only two final statuses:

```
delete from T
where exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where t2.Ref_No = T.Ref_No and t2.Id <> T.Id and (
            -- if it's not matched and there's another row that is
            T.Final_status <> 'Matched' and t2.Final_status = 'Matched'
            -- it's not the first row that's non-matched 
        or  T.Id > t2.Id and not 'Matched' in (T.Final_status, t2.Final_status)
    );
```

You could still use a `case` expression to collapse matched vs non-matched into two sortable state. This query is more portable and doesn't rely on the idea of deleting from a table expression.

Comment: Thank you @Shawnt00 for detail explanation.

Answer (score 1):

We can go for ORDER BY DESC, to make MATCHED status coming at the top, if present. If there are no MATCHED status, then EXCEPTION status will come at the top.

In this way, we only retain Rank 1 and then remove the duplicates.

```sql
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ID,Ref_No, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ref_No ORDER BY Final_Status DESC) AS rnk , Final_Status
FROM Table
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE rnk > 1
```